# How to select which JDK to run programatically

Tags: java, swing, java-8, java-7, java-web-start

I was googling for "Loading" function for `Java Swing` and ended up in this [tutorial.](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/animated-icon/)I downloaded the `.jnlp` file and try to run it. I got an error saying "**Your security settings have blocked an application from running with an out-of-date or expired version of `Java`.**"

Then something strike in mind asking how do we solve this without changing the setting.

So, my question is, can we predefine which jdk to use in the code. For an example, I have `jdk 6`, `jdk 7` and `jdk 8` in my machine, can I set in my code which `jdk` to use. Let say I want to use `jdk 6` to use how do I set in my code and can be support in other platform as well. Any advice or reference link to understand more is highly appreciated.

Comment: *"**Your security settings have blocked an application.."***  You really think you're gonna be able to side step security by specifying an earlier JRE?  That would be a huge security hole, so Oracle seems to have dropped all support for loading an earlier JRE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson are you saying that, once we upgrade the jre, there is no way to use the lower version, unless you we uninstall it. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: When you compile your application you are targeting a specfic runtime version. What you're asking for is like buying a car and when you go to get inside of one and start it, decide "I don't want this v8 engine; car, run using a 2-stroke."

Comment: *"once we upgrade the jre"*  Note that the JRE installer has had 'auto update' enabled since around late Java 1.6, so unless that is disabled in whatever JRE is used, not even uninstalling the later JRE will help for long.

Comment: @AndrewThompson you're talking specifically windows installation when talking about auto update right? The windoze installer also has the option for a static install to bypass the auto update overwriting a specifici version iirc. Don't use windoze much so could be wrong.

Comment: @Tuxxy_Thang  It is Windows and no I'm not.  Auto update, in this case, is built into the JRE.

Comment: Okay, I have only ever seen references to jre auto update in relation to windows and mac.

Comment: The user who has upgraded his JRE version might be able to relax that security restriction, however, it would be really strange if the *program code* can do it. Then it wouldn’t be a security restriction anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the java version in your code and stop execution if it is not what you want or check for other available JREs and run another jvm process on executable you want.

Or you can write a script or another program that runs before your code to do this and then run the jvm proccess.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting JAVA_HOME variable in your environmental variables. Point it to to your C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\jre
Also, in Java Control Panel you can choose your jre in the Java Runtime Environment settings

Comment: my question was how to control via coding.